# Can't create ScalingPolicy - No scalable target registered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've followed the example [here](https://github.com/1Strategy/fargate-cloudformation-example/blob/master/fargate.yaml) but when I try to update my stack I get the following error:

```
No scalable target registered for service namespace: ecs, resource ID: 
service/xxx-prod/xxx-prod-api, scalable dimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount 
(Service: AWSApplicationAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 
ObjectNotFoundException; Request ID: 1232c749-a7a9-11e9-bd34-dfed08b14539)
```

All the examples and documentation Ive seen show the resource id as something like :

```
service/cluster-name-AB678321674/service-AB672345678
```

e.g.: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-applicationautoscaling-scalabletarget.html

I dont see how or where I can get the resource id in this format.

The CF looks like this:

```
 AutoScalingTarget:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties:
      MinCapacity: !Ref MinContainers
      MaxCapacity: !Ref MaxContainers
      ResourceId: 
        Fn::Join:
        - "/"
        - - service
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Join [':', [!Ref AppStackName, 'ClusterName']]
          - !GetAtt Service.Name
      ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
      ServiceNamespace: ecs
      # "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that allows Application Auto Scaling to modify your scalable target."
      RoleARN:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join [':', [!Ref SecurityStackName, 'AutoScaleRole']]

  AutoScalingPolicy:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, AutoScalingPolicy]]
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref AutoScalingTarget
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization
        ScaleInCooldown: 10
        ScaleOutCooldown: 10
        # Keep things at or lower than 50% CPU utilization, for example
        TargetValue: !Ref AutoScalingTargetValue
```

The cluster is created in a separate stack so I have to export/import that.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same error,

Not too sure what @Jonesie means by adding them together, but there's two ways to solve this:

Either add "DependsOn: AutoScalingTarget" to AutoScalingPolicy, so the scalable target gets created before the AutoScalingPolicy

Or use ScalingTargetId in stead of ServiceNamespace/ScalableDimension/ResourceId. By using ScalingTargetId and then !Ref AutoScalingTarget you're setting up the dependency between the two resources, which is the actual problem ;)

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-applicationautoscaling-scalingpolicy.html#cfn-applicationautoscaling-scalingpolicy-scalabledimension

Comment: Im not sure what I meant either.  I think it's still working...  I guess I will find out if we ever have a disaster to recover from :)

Comment: The original post shows `ScalingTargetId: !Ref AutoScalingTarget` in the `AutoScalingPolicy`, so this answer is not relevant to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Well, FFS. I removed the target and then added the target and policy together and it works fine.

Sigh

Comment: Can you give an example? @jonesie

Comment: I think what @Jonesie meant is that if you comment out `AutoScalingTarget` and `AutoScalingPolicy` from the CFN template, update the stack, then uncomment the target/policy and update the stack again, the error will go away. This seems like an AWS/CFN bug to me.